# How to install ubuntu-device-flash in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, dependencies, ppa

I m trying to install `ubuntu-device-flash` on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bits). I'm following the instructions [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/): **Prepare your Ubuntu desktop**

I do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

... and finally `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash`

gives

```
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 ubuntu-device-flash : Depends: click-ubuntu-policy but it is not installable  
                       Depends: ubuntu-snappy-cli but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What has to be done for the installation to succeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools
```

Update (thanks Joaquin):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try the install again:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash
```

Comment: Unfortunately after doing this nothing has changed. The result is the same as before.

Comment: Correction: It solved the problem. Repository has to be updated first.
'sudo apt-get update'.

Comment: Have updated the answer, thanks for the feedback.